# Client on different IP range

Tags: networking, router, ip, nas

I had to change my router. The old one had a range of 192.168.11.1 and the new one 192.168.0.1. The problem is that I have a NAS that had an IP set to 192.168.11 and now the new router detect it, but it is out of range. How to change the IP of NAS to be in the new range?

Answer (score 0):

Set the NAS to an unused IP address in range, like `192.168.0.100`

If you're not sure which IP to use, you can set the NAS to Auto (dhcp), so that it grabs an IP from the router. Then use that IP as the new assigned address. You may have to reserve that address in the router settings so other devices don't get it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Change your router to support the range of `192.168.x.x/16`.

This will put everything on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Manually configure your computer to be in the old range, reconfigure NAS, then switch the computer back to DHCP in the new range.

The router's configuration won't matter for direct same-subnet communications.

Comment: So, do you mean to connect computer direct with NAS?

Comment: Kind of, but a direct cable connection is not necessary – it's already connected "directly enough" via the router's LAN switch. (The LAN ports being in the same subnet means that they're switched.)